# how to use regex on an unknown JSON file?

Tags: r, json, xml

Consider the following example

```
myjson <- 
  '[{
  "time": "today",
  "id": 123,
  "user": {
    "id": 456,
    "game": "playstation"
  }},
{
  "time": "today",
  "id": 555,
  "user": {
    "id": 42,
    "game": "play",
    "hobby": "station"
  }},
  {
  "time": "today",
  "id": 1,
  "user": {
    "id": 42,
    "game": "nope"
  }}
  ]'
```

I would like to quickly parse all the items in the `json` above and only keep the ones that contain `station` anywhere in any field (so, the first two items in the example, because of play**station** and **station**).

In reality, my JSON can contain nested fields of various depth, so I cannot transform the json in a dataframe easily. How can I do that? Is there a regex parser in `jsonlite`, `xml2` or others that I can use?

Thanks!

EDIT: with some more nesting we get issues

```
myjson <- 
  '[{
  "time": "today",
  "id": 123,
  "user": {
    "id": 456,
    "game": "playstation"
  }},
{
  "time": "today",
  "id": 555,
  "user": {
    "id": 42,
    "game": "play",
    "hobby": "station",
    "user": {
    "id": 10,
    "game": "play",
    "hobby": "station"
  }
  }},
  {
  "time": "today",
  "id": 1,
  "user": {
    "id": 42,
    "game": "nope"
  }}
  ]'
```

Comment: Frankly, I think starting any question with "parse json with regex" is a mistake. I'm not a pro at `jq` (a cli utility, not anything to do with R), but it might be much better suited for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps we could convert to a data.frame and then subset

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
fromJSON(myjson) %>% 
    invoke(data.frame, .) %>%
    filter(select(cur_data(), where(is.character)) %>%
                   map(~ str_detect(., 'station')) %>% 
                   reduce(`|`)
           )
```

-output

```
#   time  id user.id   user.game user.hobby
#1 today 123     456 playstation       <NA>
#2 today 555      42        play    station
```

---

If the data is heavily nested, there is a `flatten` argument in `fromJSON` which is by default `FALSE`

```
fromJSON(myjson, flatten = TRUE) %>%
     filter(select(cur_data(), where(is.character)) %>%
                   map(~ str_detect(., 'station')) %>% 
                   reduce(`|`)
           )
```

-output

```
#   time  id user.id   user.game user.hobby user.user.id user.user.game user.user.hobby
#1 today 123     456 playstation       <NA>           NA           <NA>            <NA>
#2 today 555      42        play    station           10           play         station
```

Comment: very nice. Is fromJSON flattening any kind of json nested structure?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ the `fromJSON` returns a nested third columnd with data.frame as that column.  So, i converted the whole dataset to regular data.frame with `invoke` and calling data.frame.  It would depend on the nested feature of your data

Comment: I think your parenthesis are unbalanced btw

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I checked again, by copy/pasting.  It is not showing any error on my side

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ if you meant the `filter`, the closing bracket is after the `reduce`

Comment: Thanks @akrun I am accepting but could you please have a look at the updated example? your nice solution fails on that one (it contains a nested field). Not sure why... thanks!!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ sure, i will look at it.  I didn't see any update on your post

Comment: same a logical TRUE or FALSE

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ You can use `flatten = TRUE` as in the update.  Only thing to change my be the column name with `user.user.game`, and `user.user.hobby` which can be changed depending upon how you wanted